# I need some help Identifying a component it is on the main board of an electronic speed controller

Tags: transistors, diodes, motor-controller

I have a speed controller that blew out due to a bad motor. I have since purchased a new controller and have taken it apart to see if I can fix it. I am no professional at all as I do this as a hobby but I do enjoy learning and I have not had any luck searching the internet for this part number so any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

The number on it is 
22-16L
A3 With a 2 in a circle

[image: esc board]

Answer (score 3):

It's for sure a 22uF 16V electrolytic capacitor.

Comment: Yep.  It's easy to mistake these for diodes on first glance, they've fooled me once or twice.